# In what episode of Naruto did the chief turn out to be evil?

Tags: naruto

I watched an episode where Naruto met a girl who could see the Kyubi inside of him but I can't find the episode.

Who knows the episode where that happened?

Comment: Are you talking about Karin who sensed Kyubi's chakra inside Naruto while being carried to Konoha by Kakashi?

Comment: [I think it's this movie](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Shipp%C5%ABden_the_Movie:_Bonds)

Answer (score 1):

In episode 216, Sakura tries to assassinate Sasuke. Naruto and Kakashi stop her, and Sasuke flees, leaving the red-haired Karin behind. She becomes a captive, and, while being carried back to the Hidden Leaf Villages, senses Kurama (9-tailed beast) inside Naruto.

Is this what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about the interrupt episodes, where Kabuto creates the clone of Naruto with some worm jutsu, there is a girl who can sense the 9-tails. The chief turns out to be evil.

The village is famous for its healing/potent/energetic water. I think the episode is 289 to ~296 or it may be the 389 to +a few episodes.

The drawing style is notably different, more movie like.

Comment: OP claims that it's on episode 290. Perhaps you want to update your answer.